# Foreign Keys a partir de um SqlConnection.GetSchema()

Tags: c#

É possível conseguir o nome de todas as Foreign Keys de um banco sem que eu tenha que fazer um select?

Tentei pelo GetSchema e encontrei todas as PK, IX, UQ, menos as FK.

Comment: Seus modelos estão mapeados igual se banco? Digo isso, pois é possível recuperar pelo Model, sem precisar fazer consulta no banco.

Comment: Já consegui a resposta, obg. @Randrade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sqlConnection.GetSchema("ForeignKeys");`